# Using Excel Split Function to Split Cell Contents into Multiple Columns, without having a uniform delimiter

Tags: vba, excel

I am familiar with the one cell into multiple columns feature when it comes to simple text. I have about 250 rows, where each row has a non-uniform number of list items in one cell. Some cells have as little as one list item, others have five. I need columns to be populated with each list item, separately. The columns are "First Item", "Second Item" etc. The items in the lists are non-uniform length strings.

Basically need a cell that says something like this "1. I have a dog 5. Cat 8. Today is Sunny", to have Column 1 say "1. I have a dog", Column 2 say "5. Cat", Column 3 say "8. Today is Sunny". Then process that for 250 rows.

This is some VBA I've tried, but it doesn't do anything.

```
Sub test()
Dim text As String
Dim a As Integer
Dim name As Variant
text = ActiveCell.Value
name = Split(text, "##.")
End Sub
```

Comment: So you split on the number?  Will it always have a `.` after the number on which you want to split?  Are those the only numbers in the strings?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to do. But I need to preserve the number as part of the string.

Comment: You may want to look into regex.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: Still not working when I replace the "##." with 2-25.